# "This app can't run on your PC"

Tags: windows-10, usb-storage

(Made some progress - pls.-see "***Update2***")

I am running `Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit (Version 1709, Build 16299.64)` in a VM. When trying to run documents by double-clicking them to fire the associated application, I get this message (in German, saying something that roughly translates to the text in the subject):

[image: error-message]

This happens for example for `*.flprj` ([Flare](https://www.madcapsoftware.com/products/flare/) Project Files) or `*.dyapp` ([Dyalog APL](http://dyalog.com) Applications).

As I googled, I found that often people commented it might be a 32-bit-app or it should be installed/executed as Admin. Installing/running as Admin did not change a thing as did enabling various types of compatibility modes. 
I'm not totally sure about `*.flprj`, but absolutely certain that `.dyapp` files are associated with a 64-bit-app:

> - Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.dyapp (Default)=dyappfile
> - Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dyappfile\Content Type(Default=text/plain
> - Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dyappfile\Perceived Type (Default)=text/plain
> - Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dyappfile\shell\open\command (Default)=H:\Program Files\Dyalog\Dyalog APL-64 16.0
>     Unicode\dyalog.exe DYAPP="%1"
> - Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dyappfile\Version (Default)=160

How can this be fixed?

Answering some questions that were added as comments:

- The app associated with `.dyapp` is "`H:\Program Files\Dyalog\Dyalog APL-64 16.0 Unicode\dyalog.exe"` (`H:\` is my USB-Drive)
- No problems opening the app itself with a dbl-click or from command-line, also command-line as in "open" above works (giving the name of a `.dyapp` file).
- Properties of `dyalog.exe`:

[image]

***Update 1:***

- I had a look at the `.dyapp`-double-click behaviour on my host machine where I'm running the same software and it worked. So I then searched the registry for everything related to `dyapp` on both machines and compared results and they were identical.
- I found a [recommendation](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-power/this-app-cant-run-on-your-pc/d4869176-98fa-45b7-baf9-23c083335148?auth=1) to run the "Microsoft System File Checker" who did not report any probs
- Found another comment that suggested going to "Update & Security" and enabling "For developers|Sideload apps". I had done that long before, so I turned on "Developer mode", but that did not help either.

***Update2:***

I got suspicious that perhaps the `H:\`-Drive might have been the culprit. So I uninstalled the app and re-installed on `C:\` - and sure enough it, it works fine from there! This might be a temporary fix, but I would really like to install it on `H:\` - so with the modified issue of "installing app on removable media" I hope to get closer to a solution.

Comment: When downvoting the question, I would be kind if ppl also left a comment explaining the reasoning. The problem I have is absolutely real and I tried my best to gather all required info, so I really do not see a reason for downvoting - I think that I am asking an absolutely legitimate question.

Comment: This seems to be the correct english message: https://www.google.de/search?q=this+app+can%27t+run+on+your+pc&client=firefox-b&dcr=0&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz1a_-subXAhWIVxoKHdSLBsMQ_AUICygC&biw=1618&bih=978#imgrc=P1lZZtPOBB-w7M:

Comment: Can you launch the associated application manually ? Do you still have the issue in that case ? What are the applications and versions ?

Comment: @boboes: Thanks - update the title.

Comment: @Ob1lan: more details in the question.

Comment: You have verified that dyalog.exe supports opening a file with a parameter (`dyalog.exe DYAPP="%1"`)?  Incorrect syntax would cause the error in question.

Comment: @Ramhound: yes, I use that in .BAT-Files and it works as expected

Comment: Windows is clearly confused, and I strong suspicion, the problem is the syntax your using for that key.  **If the program is installed on the H drive, why is the key, pointing to the C drive?**

Comment: Sorry, stupid mistake as explained below your answer. I apologize for misleading you!

Comment: You have verified all relevant registry keys to ... point to the correct location?  If you remove `DYAPP="%1"` from the key in question, Dyalog.exe should launch with no file open when you attempt to double click the a file with the .dyappfile file extension.  Does that happen?

Comment: Yes, I have verified that all entries referring to Dyalog.exe (V16) refer to the file on H:. Removing the DYAPP="%"-portion to launch Dyalog.exe still brings up the same error.

Comment: I've seen this problem with mapped drives before, where referencing by share name instead of drive name worked fine.

Comment: Unfortunately can't install to mapped drive, Win whines about  "can't write to.." even though I have given fulla access to everyone...

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot and may not be relevant to your situation, but it can't hurt to try.

Removable disks in Windows don't get exactly the same NTFS permissions as fixed disks. Even though when you look at the permissions and they appear to be exactly the same. Some of the more obscure permissions don't show in the Windows GUI.
And this, in turn, can lead to strange behaviour. This especially happens when launching apps, by clicking one of their documents, or when starting apps using "RunAs Different User".
I'm guessing that somehow the NTFS permissions inherit into the process that is launched to run the EXE, with one of those permissions being the cause of the problem. I have never seen it happening if the USB drive is FAT formatted.
This issue is not specific to USB drives. It can also happen with hot-pluggable SATA drives (if Windows sees them as removable, which is not always the case).

There is a workaround for this, if this is what is biting you.
Unfortunately security-wise the workaround is not very nice:
Change the NTFS permissions of the folder containing the application's executable and on all folders above that up to the root-folder to include "Full Control: EveryOne". Somehow this fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - these were already set that way...